# k-parameter Newton-Raphson maximisation

Tags: r, optimization, goodness-of-fit

I have an equation that I am integrating:

```
    integrand <- Vectorize(function(x,scale,con,time,tau,degrade,monkey){scale * (con * (time - tau)) - degrade * monkey)}

    # I have to Vectorize because I'm integrating and all the values are constats

    eq <- integrate(integrand,lower=0,upper=time)$value
```

eq gives me a concentration of monkeys which I'll refer to as M.

The data below (train and train2) found M at 7 different time points (0,20,40,60,120,240,360) during a six hour period. The way train and train2's Ms were found was NOT using this equation. This equation is an artificial way to find M.

I want to use this equation at the 7 given timepoints for the argument 'time' and fit those final 7 values of M to both train and train2's Ms.

In my equation the arguments 'scale','tau', and 'degrade' are unknown parameters. With...
con = 55;
time = 1 of the 7 timepoints;
monkey = 1 of 7 Ms (from train and train2) corresponding to the time point.

The reason I want to use train and train2 both, to find my unknown parameters is because they have different upper 't' bounds for their integrals which is specified.

So I want the values for my current unknown parameters (scale, tau, and degrade) which will result in the best global fit of the artificial 7 Ms to both train and train2 Ms.

train (t upper bound == 360)

```
timepoints          M
         0  1.0000000
        20  0.7202642
        40  0.8000305
        60  1.7430986
       120 16.5172242
       240 33.9140056
       360 34.5735984
```

train2 (t upper bound == 60)

```
timepoints          M
         0  1.0000000
        20  0.7540779
        40  0.7641358
        60  0.8694150
       120 16.5431465
       240 16.7493493
       360  6.2145258
```

I want to use a newton-raplphson maximisation fit, but i'm unsure totally how to plug in my 3 known parameters, and get the best global fit 3 unknown parameters out.

My reasoning behind choosing newton-ralphson is its ability to deal w/ k variables. If you see an easier/better way to do this, please let me know.

```
       maxNR(eq, ...? # how do I list my known parameter vector and how will it print
       # the three unknown parameters?
```

Basically I need some help writing this code, I've never used it before.

Thank you for you time